# Applying a style to and inserting a line break after the first word in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been asked to recreate an HTML site in WordPress and have it all done except for a meny bar that has me stumped. See image at: http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/8964/menubare.jpg

In short, I need a way to stylize the first word of an element differently than the rest of it and insert a line break following that first word. I'm sure it's a quick jQuery hack, but don't know enough about jQ to make it happen on my own.

Here's the catch: Those little arrows signal a drop-down menu shows up. I have the dropdowns working, but want to make sure whatever solution applies to the main menu, skips the dropdown ones (They're UL lists within an LI item).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what html mark-up would you be working with?

Comment: The menu links are at: #header #nav ul li a; and the children in the dropdowns are located at #header #nav ul li ul li a

Comment: Full HTML of the navbar is at http://pastebin.com/gu3XcG5A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an HTML example of your menu, its hard to give you a specific answer.

But you could use some jQuery like the following, it will allow you to add styling to the first word, and the rest of them. It will `.split()` the HTML on spaces, giving you an array. Wrap the first item in a span allowing styling. Then uses jQuery's `.each()` to loop through the rest of the items adding them back to the string. Then replaces the HTML with the new version:

```
$('#header > ul.nav > li > a').each(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var text = obj.html();
    var parts = text.split(' ');
    var replace = '<span class="firstWord">'+parts[0]+'</span><br />';
    parts.shift();
    $.each(parts, function(key, value) { 
        replace += ' '+value;
    });
    obj.html(replace);
});
```

Example CSS:

```
.firstWord {
    font-size: 15px;    
}
.menuHeader {
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left; 
    font-size: 40px;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #FF8C00;    
}
```

Take a look at a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aAHBg/)

---

[**Update to the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aAHBg/3/) reflect code from comment.

Use the selector:

```
$('#header > ul.nav > li > a')
```

To select only the first menu item. You should only need to add:

```
.firstWord {
    font-size: 15px;    
}
```

To your CSS to adjust the size of the first item.

---

Good suggestion by [Edwin V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167094/edwin-v), you could change the jQuery to:

```
$('#header > ul.nav > li > a').each(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var text = obj.html();
    var parts = text.split(' ');
    var replace = '<span class="firstWord">'+parts[0]+'</span><br />';
    parts.shift();
    replace += parts.join(' ');
    obj.html(replace);
});
```

To shorten it a little. [**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aAHBg/4/).

Comment: Thanks - I've put a copy of the full HTML I'm using at http://pastebin.com/gu3XcG5A if that helps.

Comment: I have changed the selector to work with your HTML, it should now add a span around the first item and a line break after it allowing you to style the first word.

Comment: Maybe consider replacing the each(parts,...) with a simple join? replace += parts.join(' '); does the trick!

Comment: Good point @Edwin V - I have added the suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#nav').children('li').find('a').each(function(){
var old = $(this).text();

$(this).html(old.substring(0,old.indexOf(' ')) +'<br/>'+old.substring(old.indexOf(' '),old.length));
});
```

if you need to apply some class

```
$(this).html('<span class="first">'+old.substring(0,old.indexOf(' ')) +'</span><br/><span class="next">'+old.substring(old.indexOf(' '),old.length)+"</span>");
```

Comment: @BrokenGlass I thought there will always be two words anyways i changed it

Comment: Ah probably my bad, I didn't look at the menu link provided by OP

Comment: This works pretty well, except on the sub-lists.

Keep in mind, I have the main list [ul][li] and then inside some of the li tags are their own [ul]s... this second nested list has to not be affected. This also doesn't seem to give me a styling option, it just inserts a break.

Comment: this wont do anything on the inner `li`'s in you want to insert some class see edit