# Add line break after some (ex. 8) words

Tags: javascript, html, replace, whitespace, words

I was searching for a script to put a line break after a number of words. I found this here in stackoverflow: [Applying a style to and inserting a line break after the first word in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451071/applying-a-style-to-and-inserting-a-line-break-after-the-first-word-in-a-link)

So, i change it a little:

```
var el = $('.wtt');   //where wtt is the class of the elements that you want to add the <br />
var text = obj.html();
var parts = text.split(' ');
//number 7 represents 8 words
$('.wtt').html($('.wtt').html().replace(parts[7],parts[7]+'<br />'));
```

Comment: Any objection against CSS: `.wtt { width:200px; word-wrap:break-word; white-space:normal;}`?

Answer (score 0):

The following would replace the 8th space in a string with a `<br>`

```
var text = 'hello there purple giraffe, how are you doing today.';
alert(text.replace(/^((\S+\s+){7}\S+)\s+/, '$1<br>'));
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space character. `\s+` matches one or more space character.